# Plugin Screenshots not showing

Tags: plugins

I've made nine revisions to my plugin and the image refuses to appear when the screenshots tab is clicked on. I placed it in the trunk initially, waited overnight, moved it to /assets, then resaved from png to jpg, read through most of the articles I could find ...... I'm stumped, Would someone else please have a look:

http://plugins.svn.wordpress.org/used-car-lot/

Comment: I see a screenshot-1.jpg in assets.

Comment: And that's where it should be be but it refuses to show up on the [screenshots](https://wordpress.org/plugins/used-car-lot/screenshots/) tab

Comment: That is not what your question asked. You should edit it to be more specific about that problem.

Answer (score 0):

If I remember right you have to put your sreeshots in the trunk/tags folder. You have your screenshots only in the media folder, which is for the header image on wordpress.org.

For further reading:

- https://wordpress.org/plugins/about/readme.txt
- https://wordpress.org/plugins/about/validator/

Comment: Taken from the first link above: "Note that the screenshot is taken from
the /assets directory or the directory that contains the stable readme.txt (tags or trunk). **Screenshots in the /assets 
directory take precedence.** For example, `/assets/screenshot-1.png` "would win over `/tags/4.3/screenshot-1.png`